# Using lambda function in python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I just came across `lambda` function in python, so just tried to play with it.
Here I tried

```
a="ABCD"
b=map(lambda x:a[int(x)],a)
print(list(b))
```

And this gives error
`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'`
but was expecting O/P like this

`[A,B,C,D]`

Any explanation on this .

Thanks

Comment: `lambda x:a[int(x)]` this is not a `lambda` function that capitalizes letters..

Comment: Why are you calling `int` on a letter? What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Why not just `list(a)`?

Comment: Can you explain what you think the `lambda` function is doing?

Comment: I thought `b=map(lambda x:a[x],a)` would be like a[x] would be like `a[i]`

Comment: That could be true for a dictionary but that's not how lists/strings work, the index must be the *position* of the value you want to access.

Comment: @yinnonsanders but `a[0]` gives you `A`

Comment: Yes, but `int('A')` is not `0`, it's undefined. The fact that `A` is in the `0`th position of `a` doesn't determine the meaning of `int()`. Anyway, `map` applies the function in the first argument to every element in the second argument, in this case `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`, `'D'`

Comment: @Domnick your argument x for the lamda function, contains the values [A,B,C,D] one after another, so you can directly operate on the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

int(x) yields your error, since you can not convert "A" into an integer

Correct would be:

```
a="ABCD"
b=map(lambda x:x,a)
print(list(b))
```

As mentioned in the comments, the following gives the same result:

```
print(list(a))
```

You should probably check out some more lambda tutorials first: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk

Answer (score 0):

You can not convert `alphabates` directly into `int`, you can make use of `ord()`

```
In [8]: a="ABCD"

In [9]: b=map(lambda x:x,a)

In [10]: print(list(b))
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

Comment: You can... the `ord` function does just that.

Comment: yes right but directly alphabet you can't @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ